# How to add scope-like method in a controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dry, rspec-rails

Another variation of this question: **How to test controller scopes in DRY style?**

I have a lot of scopes in controller:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :require_admin
  before_filter :navigation, only: [:show, :edit]

  def show
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t(:thank_you_for_your_subscription) if params[:p]
  end

  def edit
    render_not_found and return unless %w(username password).include?(params[:section])

    @section = params[:section]
  end
...
```

So, I have a lot of similar methods in controller specs (for actions). The typical controller spec is:

```
describe SettingsController do
  let!(:user) { Factory(:user) }

  describe "GET #show" do
    def do_action
      get :show
    end

    it_requires_sign_in
    it_requires_admin
    it_specifies_navigation_with 'settings'

    it "should set a flash message when the 'p' param is set" do
      sign_in_as user
      do_action
      flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
    end
  end

  describe "GET #edit" do
    def do_action options = {}
      get :edit, options.merge(format: 'rjs')
    end

    it_requires_sign_in
    it_requires_admin
    it_specifies_navigation_with 'settings'

    context "when singed in" do
      before { sign_in_as user }

      it "should render 404 if no section is provided" do
        do_action
        response.code.should == '404'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But `it_requires_sign_in` method has next representation:

```
def it_requires_sign_in
  it "should require sign in" do
    send do_action
    response.should redirect_to(sign_in_path)
  end
end
```

Navigation:

```
def it_specifies_navigation_with(name)
  it "specifies navigation with '#{name}'" do
    controller.should receive(:current_navigation).with(name)
    sign_in_as user
    do_action
  end
end
```

So, it uses method from describe part. Is it possible to make some kind of scope in which i could specify methods (actions), that i want to check or not, like:

```
describe SettingsController do
  requires_sign_in # every action (inner describe parts)
  requires_admin
  specifies_navigation_with only: [:show, :edit]

  let!(:user) { Factory(:user) }

  describe "GET #show" do
    def do_action
      get :show
    end

    it "should set a flash message when the 'p' param is set" do
      sign_in_as user
      do_action
      flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
    end
  end
...
```

The main problem is to call the exact method `do_action` in precise scope (i mean describe action part).

Comment: The thing is, each has a different `do_action`, is there a way to make them almost the same and pass the difference as an argument?

Comment: They all have different options, so it's impossible i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not focus to dry to much. Specs are a kind of documentation. Therefore I think specs should be:

- **readable**: Trying to much dry may lead to specs that are not easy to read and understand.
- **easy to change**: It is likely that your need to change an action in your controller. This should be possible without changing specs for other actions.

Therefore I think it is okay to repeat yourself in specs.

If I had to spec that part of the controller I would start with defining a shared example:

```
# shared example for authenticated admins 
RSpec.shared_examples 'an action only for authenticated admins' do
  describe 'before_filter :authenticate' do
    context 'with an user signed in' do
      before { sign_in_as(user) }

      it 'does not redirect' do
        expect(response).to_not redirect_to(sign_in_path)
      end

    end

    context 'without an user' do
      it 'redirects to the sign in page' do
        expect(response).to redirect_to(sign_in_path)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'before_filter :require_admin' do
    before { sign_in_as(user) }

    context 'when user is an admin' do
      before { allow(user).to receive(:admin?).and_return(true) }

      it 'does something' do
        # check something
      end
    end

    context 'when user is not an admin' do
      before { allow(user).to receive(:admin?).and_return(false) }

      it 'does something other' do
        # check something other
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'before_filter :navigation' do
    before do 
      allow(controller).to receive(:current_navigation).and_return_original
      allow(user).to receive(:admin?).and_return(true) 
      sign_in_as(user)
    end

    it 'sets the current navigation name' do
      response
      expect(controller).to have_received(:current_navigation).with(navigation_name)
    end
  end
end
```

See the [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) for more examples how to use shared examples.

In the controller spec itself you will notice that I am very explicit about every single step preparing my example and the different contexts. Furthermore I prefer the new `expect(...).to` syntax over the old `(...).should` syntax.

```
describe SettingsController do
  let(:user) { Factory(:user, :admin => true) }

  describe 'GET show' do
    subject(:response) { get :show }

    it_behaves_like 'an action only for authenticated admins' do
      let(:navigation_name) { 'settings' }
    end

    context 'with an admin signed in' do
      before { sign_in_as(user) }

      it 'shows a flash message' do
        response
        expect(flash[:notice]).to_not be_nil
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'GET edit' do
    subject(:response) { get :edit, { format: 'rjs' } }

    it_behaves_like 'an action only for authenticated admins' do
      let(:navigation_name) { 'settings' }
    end

    context 'with an admin signed in' do
      before { sign_in_as(user) }

      it 'shows a flash message' do
        expect(response.code).to eq('404')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: However, I disagree that style, that I want to implement is less readable.

Comment: Perhaps is *readable* not the right word here. But shared examples are part of RSpec and therefore the right solution for this problem. Most developer that are familiar with RSpec also know shared examples and understand them. If you choose to write methods that add examples, when I think this is unexpected and might make it harder for other developers to understand your code.

Comment: Of course I aware about shared examples. I just think that it can be done easier. [This](https://github.com/errbit/errbit/blob/master/spec/controllers/apps_controller_spec.rb) example uses scope technique, and it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share with you what I have in mind and you could decide if it's useful or not

```
describe SettingsController do
  def do_action_with(options={})
    get options[:action], options[:args]
  end

  shared_example_for 'a page that requires sign in' do
    do_action_with(action: action, args: args)
    response.should redirect_to(sign_in_path)
  end

  describe "GET #show" do
    it_behaves_like 'a page that requires sign in' do
      let(action) { :show }
      let(args) { [] }
    end

    it "should set a flash message when the 'p' param is set" do
      sign_in_as user
      do_action_with(action: :show, args: []) #maybe move these params as a global for the #show example
      flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
    end
  end

  describe "GET #edit" do
    it_behaves_like 'a page that requires sign in' do
      let(action) { :edit }
      let(args) { ['rjs'] }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's good approach to make general method for all actions, i'll try it and accept if no one suggests better. Thanks.

Comment: However, it doesn't resolve the main problem, there are still `it_behaves_like` for each feature like `requires_sign_in`, `requires_admin`, and i have more.

Answer (score 1):

Having a lot of experience with RSpec in big projects I would suggest another approach entirely. While purist BDD approach seems like the way to do, in practice it means long running test suites due to non critical tests that no developer wants to run.

In your given example testing that every controller action requires admin login might seem like a correct approach, however what you're really doing is increasing your controller specs suite size by 30% or so. Ask yourself what developer would simply remove `before_filter :authenticate` when refactoring? What you really want is test the `:authenticate` method itself.

So how does it look in practice?

```
describe ApplicationController do
  describe "#authenticate" do
    controller do
      before_action :authenticate

      def index
        render nothing: true
      end
    end

    it "redirects to sign in path if user is not signed in" do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(sign_in_path)
    end

    it "renders page if user is signed in" do
      sign_in @user
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that I'm testing **application controller** here. I'm also testing authenticate method itself instead of testing whether `before_action :authenticate` was called. Note: if authenticate method comes from something like devise, I wouldn't even write these 2 tests and just trust devise authors to have tested this.

TL;DR - Test body of method not the one line macro that calls it.

Comment: Thanks for tips. The point is, `:require_admin` are usually goes with `except`, so my specs check the presence of `require_admin` for some actions. But I think you meant that it's too simple to test, that's fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of spickermann's answer, here is how I would solve your do_action problem. Shared examples can be passed params like so:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "admin only route" do |method, route, params={}|
  it "fails without authentication" do
    send(method, route, params)
    expect(response.code).to eq("401")
  end

  it "succeeds with authentication" do
    login
    send(method, route, params)
    expect(response.code).not_to eq("401")
  end
  ...
end
```

In order to use this in your spec just call it like this:

```
it_behaves_like("authenticated route", :post, :create, {name: 'bob'})
```

Comment: it will be performed in context of current action spec, so i could call my `do_action` method.